# Enabling XML style documentation for a new project type in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xml-documentation

How do I enable XML style documentation for a new project type I'm creating in Visual Studio? Also, is there a way I can edit an existing project type to allow XML style documentation (NOT talking about checking the XML documentation file in the Builds property of a C# project)?

Scenario:
I have a new project type I have created. I want to insert a template any time the user types in '///' in this project type.

Comment: SO, if a developer types /// you want to insert a text block different than default one: <summary></summary>?
Are you ready to handle <param>-s? :)

Comment: Well, right now I don't even get the <summary> tags since this is not a default VS project type like C# or VB. This is a new project type I have. So, I am willing to take even the <summary> tags but I need something! :)